# POST by cURL resulting in empty array in PHP

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, curl

I'm trying to post data via cURL command line to php. It appears to me that it is working, but the receiving page just shows an empty array.

LAMP stack on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, PHP is 7.4.

Here is my command line cURL, -v output.

```
$ curl -v -d "name=rabbit" https://example.com/test1.php -H "connection: close"
*   Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=example.com
*  start date: Oct  6 01:42:48 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Jan  4 01:42:47 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "example.com" matched cert's "example.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /test1.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> connection: close
> Content-Length: 23
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 23 out of 23 bytes
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 07 Oct 2021 19:25:25 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 81
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
array(1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "rabbit"
}
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
```

Test page is just

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Does the output indicate that it is successfully posting the data? Log files on the receiving server show 200. php-curl is of course installed and enabled. Am I missing a dependency or a config change I need to make to receive POST by cURL?

TIA

Comment: looks like it was successful

Comment: In that case, any idea why the posted array is empty? The page displays $_POST when submitted via HTML form.

Comment: what then is `"array(1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "rabbit"
}"` ??

Comment: That is the verbose output of the curl command showing what array it sent. The issue is that the receiving PHP shows an empty $_POST array after the successful curl. I'm not familiar with curl, so I wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something there. At this point, I have to assume there is a receiving server-side configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used `curl` before from the command line so it took a little time to find it an figure what to do with the myriad of options available. I created a similar file to your `test.php` script but to illustrate that the POST request is being processed added some more data.

```
<?php
    /*
        The command issued on cmd line:
        curl -v -d "name=geronimo&tribe=apache&wife=alope&hobby=alcohol" --cacert "c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem" -k https://sentinel/demo/curl-test.php
    */
    ob_clean();
    
    #new data
    $_POST['date']=date( DATE_ATOM );
    $_POST['ip']=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    
    #format & print output
    exit( sprintf( '%1$s%2$s%1$s', str_repeat( PHP_EOL, 1 ), print_r( $_POST, true ) ) );
    
?>
```

Then issuing the above (&following) command on commandline:

```
curl -v -d "name=geronimo&tribe=apache&wife=alope&hobby=alcohol" --cacert "c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem" -k https://sentinel/demo/curl-test.php
```

Yielded the following verbose output with modified POST data:

```
* About to connect() to sentinel port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.0.57... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=GB; ST=Angus; L=Forfar; O=TrekSafe; OU=Web Development; CN=sentinel; emailAddress=web@sentinel
*        start date: 2021-04-09 07:09:17 GMT
*        expire date: 2022-04-08 07:09:17 GMT
*        subjectAltName: sentinel matched
*        issuer: O=AO Kaspersky Lab; CN=Kaspersky Anti-Virus Personal Root Certificate
*        SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
> POST /demo/curl-test.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.23.1 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.23.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1
.2.5
> Host: sentinel
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 51
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 51 out of 51 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 08 Oct 2021 12:41:50 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.9
< Upgrade: h2,h2c
< Connection: Upgrade
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.9
< Content-Length: 167
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<

Array
(
    [name] => geronimo
    [tribe] => apache
    [wife] => alope
    [hobby] => alcohol
    [date] => 2021-10-08T13:41:50+01:00
    [ip] => 192.168.0.57
)

* Connection #0 to host sentinel left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

You can see the modified POST data in the response roughly where the data is shown in your original code. The fact that there is a `200` http response code should tell you the request was successful.